# Include label attribute into kable header

Tags: html, r, knitr, r-markdown

**Reproducible example:**

I have a data frame which has labelled variables to represent units using the [sjmisc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjmisc/index.html) package, which works nicely together with [dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html) since v0.4.2.

```
library(dplyr)
library(sjmisc)
library(ggplot2)
data("diamonds")

df= tbl_df(diamonds) %>%
select(cut, carat, color, price) %>%
set_label(c("", "Kt", "Type","EUR")) %>%
slice(1:5)
```

As `str(df)` shows it properly contains for three columns the labels:

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   5 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ cut  : Ord.factor w/ 5 levels "Fair"<"Good"<..: 5 4 2 4 2
 $ carat: atomic  0.23 0.21 0.23 0.29 0.31
  ..- attr(*, "label")= Named chr "Kt"
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "carat"
 $ color: Ord.factor w/ 7 levels "D"<"E"<"F"<"G"<..: 2 2 2 6 7
  ..- attr(*, "label")= Named chr "Type"
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "color"
 $ price: atomic  326 326 327 334 335
  ..- attr(*, "label")= Named chr "EUR"
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "price"
```

Also with the [R-Studio IDE](https://www.rstudio.com) I can see the labels `View(df)`.

[image]

Now I want to print this data frame via the [knitr/rmarkdown/html](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html) toolchain as html using the `kable` function from [knitr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitr/index.html) with following code as `.Rmd` [rmarkdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com) file.

````
---
title: "Table with labels"
output: html_document
---

```{r include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(sjmisc)
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)
data("diamonds")
```

## Example

```{r echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
df= tbl_df(diamonds) %>%
  select(cut, carat, color, price) %>%
  set_label(c("", "Kt", "Type","EUR")) %>%
  slice(1:5)

kable(df)
```
````

which leads to an html which contain the following table:

[image]

**Problem:**

So unfortunately, the labels for the units are not used as second line in the header.

**Question:**

How can I get the "Kt"  below the "carat", the "Type" below the "color" and "EUR" below the "price" as a second header row ? The second row shall have same horizontal centering as the first row.

I am looking for a solution without manually adding the labels by hand to the second line, it should automatically apply the labels to the printed table. When possible the unit labels shall have a bit smaller font size than the first row header line or alternatively have no bold font.

How can `kable` (in this case for html output) be rewritten to fulfill these requirements and play well together with labelled data frames ?

Comment: I think this is too broad. `kable` is actually multiple programs and you  seem to have more requirements than would be reasonable to expect a compact solution. Look at the code. You can see that kable actually calls one of  4 separate programs: `res = do.call(paste("kable", format, sep = "_"),` where format is one of:  "markdown",  "latex", "html", "rst".

Comment: What? Isn't this [exactly the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34692402/include-label-attribute-into-xtable-header), except for the output format which is HTML in this and PDF in the other question? This doen't make this question a duplicate, but please add such information to the question the next time you ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description for `kable` tells us

> This is a very simple table generator. It is simple by design. It is not intended to replace any other R packages for making tables.

So I don't expect you'll be able to do this directly with `kable`.  There are other options however.  They will vary in terms of verbosity, simplicity and efficiency.

Here's one approach using the `pixiedust` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(sjmisc)
library(ggplot2)
library(pixiedust)
data("diamonds")

df= tbl_df(diamonds) %>%
  select(cut, carat, color, price) %>%
  set_label(c("", "Kt", "Type","EUR")) %>%
  slice(1:5)

Head <- rbind(names(df),
              get_label(df)) %>%
  as.data.frame(., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dust(df) %>%
  redust(., Head, part = "head") %>%
  sprinkle_print_method("html")
```

You can use other functions in the `pixiedust` package to customize the look of the table (and the formatting of tables can easily be bundled into custom functions to make it easier to apply the formatting in the future).

I'm sure `htmlTables` can do this as well, though I'm not as proficient with it.